# How to convert MongoDB ISODate array elements to formatted string elements in mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB database I have, introduced by error, some `ISODate`s, and I need to change them to string format.

I have tried to update them one by one with the `updateOne`, selecting the element of the array where the wrong element is and changing it by the correct string. This works, but I need to do this for many records so I need to automate it.

I need that the current elements similar to `ISODate("2013-02-25T16:01:50.742Z")` that are inside a collection like `db.myCollection.elements.myArray.0.date`are changed to a string format like `"2013-02-25 16:01:50"`.

Also, I need to find, for all the elements of the array, the date, that is in ISO format, convert it into the string one, and update it.

The format of the document in myCollection is like:

```
{
   elements: 
   [
      { date: ISODate("2019-03-14T02:42:00Z")},
      { date: ISODate("2019-03-14T02:42:00Z")}
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is the number in the string "20130225160150"? What does it represent (in what terms e.g., seconds, millis, etc.). Plesase clarify. What is the logic you want to apply to convert?

Comment: See if these can help: [Date Expression Operators (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators).

Comment: The string is supposed to be just a string format for the timestamp. Like yyyymmddHHMMHH, for instance

Comment: There are some missing characters in the string format. The hyphens ("-") are not there and the last few characters are not there. So, what is it you want in the string? "yyyymmddHHMMSS" ? _Please be specific._

Comment: Just edited. I think with hyphens it will be OK for me. I don't need the last characters, just until the seconds

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: 3.6 from the dockerhub

Answer (score 0):

> I need that the current elements similar to
>   ISODate("2013-02-25T16:01:50.742Z") that are inside a collection like
>   db.myCollection.elements.myArray.0.date are changed to a string format
>   like "2013-02-25 16:01:50"
>
> So I need to find, for all the elements of
>   the array, the date, that is in ISO format, convert it into the string
>   one, and update it.

Sample `dates3` collection:.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dt" : [ ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:09Z"), ISODate("2019-11-02T16:01:48.066Z") ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dt" : [ ISODate("2019-11-02T14:38:26Z"), "not date" ] }
{ "_id" : 9 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : "not array" }
```

The update is run from the mongo shell:

```
db.dates3.aggregate( [
{ $addFields: { dateArrayExists: { $isArray: "$dt" } } },
{ $match: { dateArrayExists: true } },
{ $project: { dt: { $map: { 
                         input: "$dt", 
                         as: "d", 
                         in: { $cond: { 
                                  if: { $eq: [ "date", { $type: "$$d" }  ] }, 
                                  then: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$$d" } }, 
                                  else: "$$d" 
                                } 
                         } }
} } }
] ).forEach( doc => db.dates3.save(doc) );
```

The `dates3` collection is updated:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dt" : [ "2019-05-23 23:05:09", "2019-11-02 16:01:48" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dt" : [ "2019-11-02 14:38:26", "not date" ] }
{ "_id" : 9 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : "not array" }
```

---

**[ EDIT ADD ]**

**For Updated Requirement:**

> I need that the current elements similar to
>   `ISODate("2013-02-25T16:01:50.742Z")` that are inside a collection
>   like db.myCollection.elements.myArray.0.date are changed to a string
>   format like `"2013-02-25 16:01:50"`.
>
> Also, I need to find, for all the elements of the array, the date,
>   that is in ISO format, convert it into the string one, and update it.
>
> The format of the document in `myCollection` is like:
>
> ```
> {
>    elements: 
>    [
>       { date: ISODate("2019-03-14T02:42:00Z")},
>       { date: ISODate("2019-03-14T02:42:00Z")}
>    ]
> }
> ```

Input Collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dt" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:09Z") }, { "date" : ISODate("2019-11-02T16:01:48.066Z") } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dt" : [ { "date" : ISODate("2019-11-02T14:38:26Z") }, { "date" : "not date" } ] }
{ "_id" : 9 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : "not array" }
```

The Update Query:

```
db.dates5.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { dateArrayExists: { $isArray: "$dt" } } },
  { $match: { dateArrayExists: true } },
  { $unwind: "$dt" },
  { $project: { "dt.date": {  $cond: { 
                                      if: { $eq: [ "date", { $type: "$dt.date" }  ] }, 
                                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$dt.date" } }, 
                                      else: "$dt.date"
                                                  }  } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", dt: { $push: { date: "$dt.date"} } } },
]).forEach( doc => db.dates5.save(doc) );
```

The Updated Collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "dt" : [ { "date" : "2019-05-23 23:05:09" }, { "date" : "2019-11-02 16:01:48" } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "dt" : [ { "date" : "2019-11-02 14:38:26" }, { "date" : "not date" } ] }
{ "_id" : 9 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : "not array" }
```

Comment: How would this change if the ISODate is inside a field, so maybe the first first would be something like: { "_id" : 1, "dt" : [{start:  ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:09Z")}, {end: ISODate("2019-11-02T16:01:48.066Z") }] } This is actually the case

Comment: Please update the post with a proper example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I've just added an example of the format of the relevant part of the document of the collection that I'm using